# How to load collection view at bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collection view that displays messages. Right now it loads the messages and then scrolls to the bottom

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

This works but with a large number of messages and collectionview items it scrolls really slowly and is really choppy.
What I want to happen is that the collection view starts at the bottom and doesn't have to scroll through all the messages and look like it does on message. I also tried this but it didn't work

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.collectionView.frame.size.height)
self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to scroll through the messages and reach to the bottom at once set the `animated` parameter to `false`.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `viewDidLoad` bottom, it works fine in iOS 13, I'm not test in other versions:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastIndexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
}
```

If you put your second code into `DispatchQueue.main.async`, it should work, (I think...)